# Weird characters when allocating memory for char*

Tags: c, char, malloc

Hy I have a sample code bleow, which should write the "MSG" in a way an LCD display would (running text) and when it reached the end it strarts again, but when I allocate memory for the "LCD" (which schould be 10 character+terminating 0) fills it with bunch of random characters.
[Sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjILB.png)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <time.h>



void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}

int main()
{

    int LCDSize = 10;
    int MSGSize;
    char* LCD = (char *)malloc(LCDSize+1);
    char* MSG = (char *)malloc(80);
    MSG = "This is a long message, probabli will move.";
    MSGSize = strlen(MSG);
    if (MSGSize <= LCDSize)
    {
        printf(MSG);
    }
    else
    {
        char* tmpMSG;
        int j = 0;
        while (j < 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MSGSize - LCDSize + 1; i++)
            {
                tmpMSG = MSG+i;
                strncpy(LCD, tmpMSG, LCDSize);
                strcat(LCD,"\0");
                printf(LCD);
                delay(200);
                system("cls");

            }
            printf("----------");
            j++;
        }
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Using `printf(MSG);` is not a good idea; you should use `printf("%s", MSG);`.  It isn't so critical here because the user cannot control the content of the message and the message contains no percent symbols (if everything is working correctly), but in general with user-provided data to print, what you used is potentially lethal.  They're called 'format string vulnerabilities'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            strncpy(LCD, tmpMSG, LCDSize);
            strcat(LCD,"\0");
```

The `strncpy` function will not terminate if it doesn't fit. In this case, it doesn't fit. So there is no termination. Something that is not terminated with a zero byte is *not* a legal string, so you cannot pass a pointer to it as the first parameter to `strcat`, but you do.

The `strcat` function appends one string onto another. Both strings must be legal, well-formed strings or you must not call `strcat`.

This is one of the reasons it is generally suggested that you *not* use `strncpy` -- there is no guarantee the result is a valid string and it's easy to make the kind of mistake you made. Yes, you made sure you didn't overflow the buffer when you called `strncpy` by limiting the size, but you didn't ensure the buffer contained a valid string.

What you probably wanted was `LCD[LCDSize]='\0';` instead of the call to `strcat`. This ensures the buffer is terminated.

Comment: Technically speaking, any buffer is eventually terminated with a zero byte, so any buffer is in fact a legal string :)

Comment: @m0skit0: No.  If there is no null byte within the space allocated for the bufferr, the buffer is not a legal string.  There will, eventually, be a zero byte somewhere outside the range of the buffer that will probably be treated as the termination for the string, but you're incurring 'undefined behaviour' long before that — anything could happen.